# How to send over a Dart Firebase DatabaseReference to native

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

Alright, suggestions for the title are welcome but I couldn't come up with anything better.

But here is what I'm trying to do:
I'm trying to create a GeoFire plugin for Flutter. GeoFire needs a reference to the Firebase database but the Firebase plugin for Flutter uses a custom `DatabaseReference` class. So how would I get that data to the native side and convert it to the appropriate class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`path`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/firebase_database/0.1.0/firebase_database/Query/path.html) property of the `firebase_database` plugin's `DatabaseReference` class to serialize it to a `String`. You can pass the `path` to native-land using platform channels and use it to construct an equivalent native [`FIRDatabaseReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabase#-referencewithpath) (on iOS) or [`DatabaseReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#getReference(java.lang.String)) (on Android) using the native Firebase APIs.